# Weird behavior of.as.POSIXct in R

Tags: r, datetime

I have a column with the date time in character, such as "2015-03-08 02:38:05"

however when i applied the transformation of `as.POSIXct` most of them converted but some of them reported NA. I further dig into the ones with NA result but did not see anything different from others. I tried the individual values and the `as.POSIXct` still throws an error. For example:
This one will report NA

```
as.POSIXct("2015-03-08 02:38:05", format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

But this one won't

```
as.POSIXct("2015-04-18 02:47:11", format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

[image]

Comment: sorry i got the wrong screenshot..please see the update

Comment: Daylight savings time?  2:38 may not have been a valid time on March 8th.

Comment: @Dave2e I guess it is due to the timezone. But it is so weird that 2:38 does not exist...

Comment: This has tripped up others.  The weird part is daylight savings starts so early in the year:(